# My iMac’s Boot Camp assistant rejects Windows 10 ISO, says it must be Windows 7 or higher?

Tags: iso-image, boot-camp, imac

I downloaded the Windows 10 ISO files, and inserted a USB drive into my iMac (27-inch, Late 2012) which is running OS X is 10.8.5.

When I run Boot Camp Assistant, select the proper ISO image, and click “Continue”, it shows a pop-up that says:

> “Boot Camp only supports Windows 7 or later installation on this platform. Please use an ISO file for Windows 7 or later installation.”

I’m not sure whether it’s an error on my part, or just my system isnot compatible.

How can I get Windows 10 installed on this iMac?

FWIW, I downloaded the 64 bit ISO file, and according to the app store it says that there are no updates available.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what version of macOS you're running on that iMac.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you're running some ancient version of macOS and thus an ancient version of Boot Camp Assistant which doesn't know how to handle Windows 10. For best results, use the Mac App Store / Software Updates to update your macOS (for free!) to the latest version that supports your machine (looks like it was probably 10.15 Catalina), boot that version of macOS, run Software Updates until you have a fully up-to-date instance of that macOS version, and then run Boot Camp Assistant from there.

Comment: @Spiff According to the details on the [Wikipedia “Boot Camp” page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)#Mac_OS_X_10.7_Lion_and_OS_X_10.8_Mountain_Lion) it seems that Mac OS X 10.8 supports Windows 10 Home, Pro, Pro for Workstation, Education or Enterprise (64-bit editions only). So nice theory, but it seems like this iMac _should_ at least running Windows 10 of some kind.

Comment: @curious It's a little counterintuitive, but the App Store app won't list major macOS upgrades as available updates to apps you own, since each major macOS update installer was listed as a separate app. So search the app store for macOS, find the latest major macOS installer it offers, and install and boot from that. Repeat this process if necessary until you're on macOS Catalina (10.15). Then run System Preferences > Software Updates (note: not the app store this time) to make sure you have all updates available. The latest Boot Camp you can run will have the most compatibility and bug fixes.

Comment: Based on [the info on this site](https://everymac.com/systems/by_capability/maximum-macos-supported.html), the max macOS version compatible with a Late 2012 iMac is macOS 10.15.x.

Comment: To save any nasty surprises - 32-bit is gone entirely from Catalina - I'd only go as far as Mojave, 10.14. It would also be wise to do it in increments, specifically to go first to El Capitan 10.11, then if it will allow, straight to Mojave [it *may* want you to go via High Sierra 10.13 first, though the newer installers appear to be able to jump past that] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos for more detail, including links to each OS.